# Get all categories belonging to one collection

Tags: jekyll

Using jekyll, I would like to get all categories that belong to exactly one of my collections. Currently, I have two collections defined in my `_config.yaml`:

```
collections:
  posts:
    output: true
    permalink: /blog/:title/
  press_releases:
    output: true
    permalink: /press/:title/
```

I learned that by using `site.categories` I can access all categories that are currently mentioned in my posts. The problem is that I would like to get only those categories related to either one of these two collections. Meaning only categories from press_releases OR categories from posts. Is there something like `site.posts.categories` or `site.press_releases.categories`?

At the moment, it seems that by calling `site.categories` I only get those categories from my collection `posts`.

I searched for other similar cases but haven't found a single one so far. Does jekyll not support separating categories according to collections or am I having a wrong idea of how to use collections and categories?

Comment: As far as I have experienced posts are handled different from collections (in many ways). I think this is a design flaw in Jekyll that reminds me of WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

No, Jekyll does not provide an attribute to access the categories for just one collection. However, this can be done with some liquid code.

```
{% for my_doc in site.press_releases %}

{% for category in my_doc.categories %}
  {% capture my_categories %}
    {% if my_categories %}
      {{ my_categories | join: "," }},{{ category }}
    {% else %}
       {{ category }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endcapture %}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

{% assign my_categories = my_categories | split: "," | uniq %}

{% for cat in my_categories %}
  {{cat }}
{% endfor %}
```

Basically what we do here is, get all documents of the desired collection, cycle through all documents and get the categories as stored in frontmatter (or defaults) and collect them in an array. Note, array operations in liquid are a bit clumsy, why we need to convert an array to a string back and forth. In the above code, the final for-loop should give you all categories of your collection 'press_releases'.

Comment: thanks a lot for posting this! I can't test this right, but this is exactly what I was having in mind! Will keep you posted.